# Approximation of gamma function via Riemann sums at integer points

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, approximation, factorial, gamma-function

I found something curious. We know that the gamma function is defined as
$$ \Gamma(n+1) := \int_{t=0}^\infty t^n \exp(-t) dt,$$
and it has the property that $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ for non-negative integer $n$. I recently came across the following Riemann sum approximation of the gamma function:
$$ S(n) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^n \exp(-k). $$
A priori there is no reason to suspect that $S(n)$ should approximate $\Gamma(n+1)$ at all, since the points are integer, so they are not getting closer.

However, I plugged in a couple of values of this sum into Wolfram Alpha (e.g., https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+exp%28-n%29+n%5E6) and saw that, to my surprise, $S(n)$ has a closed form (some messy formula), and numerically $S(n)$ is pretty close to $n!$, seemingly improving as $n$ gets large.

Is this known? How do we derive the closed form for the sums in general? I tried searching but couldn't find anything. Any pointers would be super helpful! Ultimately I want to prove that $S(n)$ approximates $n!$ as $n$ gets large so any ideas for showing that would also be helpful.

Comment: Based on the output of Wolfram Alpha and OEIS, the infinite sums are of the form of a polynomial of degree $n$ in $e$ related to the Eulerian numbers / polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) divided by $(e-1)^{n+1}$ . Since the original basis for the Eulerian numbers was characterizing certain permuations, the convergence is not surprising.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the pointer. The second equation under the identities section seems quite relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula should make the relationship clearer- the remainder term has forward differences of derivatives that are very convenient given the recursive properties of the gamma function and its derivatives. You can use of $\partial_x \Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x)\digamma(x)$ to help make sense of it.

Comment: $$
S(n)=\left(-\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-tk}\Bigg|_{t=1}=\left(-\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n\frac{1}{e^t-1}\Bigg|_{t=1}
$$

Comment: @Cameron King That is super helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Gonçalo that's brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a variation of Gonçalo's argument. We will consider the exponential generating function of the $S(n)$, namely

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{S(n)}{n!} z^n &=& \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{k^n z^n}{n!} \right) \exp(-k) \\
 &=& \sum_{k \ge 0} \exp(kz) \exp(-k) \\
 &=& \frac{1}{1 - \exp(z-1)}. \end{eqnarray*}$$

The asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of this generating function can be described using meromorphic singularity analysis, as described e.g. in [Flajolet and Sedgewick](https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf). The dominant pole occurs at $z = 1$ with residue $1$ which is responsible for the dominant term of the asymptotic $\frac{S(n)}{n!} \approx 1$. The error is dominated by the poles next closest to the origin, which occur at $z = 1 \pm 2 \pi i$; this gives (with a bit more work)

$$\boxed{ \frac{S(n)}{n!} = 1 + O \left( \frac{1}{|1 + 2 \pi i|^n} \right) }.$$

Here $|1 + 2 \pi i| = \sqrt{1 + 4 \pi^2} = 6.362 \dots $ so, for example, for $n = 6$ the multiplicative error is on the order of $1.5 \times 10^{-5}$. However, this exponential does grow more slowly than the factorial so the additive error does eventually increase.

Closed forms for any particular $n$ can also be deduced by expanding the generating function. They are probably related to some well-known sequence of polynomials but I'm not sure which. I also don't know what bounds you get from applying Euler-Maclaurin here.

Comment: By the way, getting a pretty good approximation here is not so surprising as it might first appear. Take a look at the graph of $x^n \exp(-x)$ for, say, $n = 10$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%5E10+e%5E%28-x%29+from+x+%3D+0+to+20); it is roughly a bell curve centered at $n$. Working out the shape of this bell curve gives you Stirling's approximation, and as $n$ increases you sample more and more points from this bell curve (after adjusting for its width). Moreover the Riemann sum is an overestimate on one side and an underestimate on the other.

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks for the pointer, always so much to learn (I've not seen any analytic combinatorics before). You're right, in hindsight it is perhaps not so surprising.

Comment: @N-7: Flajolet and Sedgewick is a wonderful book, lots of stuff worth learning in there even if you're not interested in combinatorics per se.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to extend this approach to give error bounds on $S(r)/\Gamma(r+1)$ for non-integer positive $r$?

Comment: @N-7: not easily. You can write down a generation function for, say, $S(n + r)$ for arbitrary $r$ but you end up having to evaluate something that looks like a polylogarithm anyway so I think in that case Gary's approach makes more sense.

Comment: @N-7 See my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

The difference may be expressed explicitly using the [known expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E12) of the polylogarithm:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k^n \mathrm{e}^{ - k} } & = \operatorname{Li}_{ - n} (\mathrm{e}^{ - 1} ) = \Gamma (n + 1) + \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \frac{{\zeta ( - n - m)}}{{m!}}} 
\\& = \Gamma (n + 1) - 2\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \frac{{\Gamma (n + m)}}{{\Gamma (m)}}\frac{{\zeta (n + m)}}{{(2\pi )^{n + m} }}\cos \left( {\frac{{\pi (n + m)}}{2}} \right)}
\end{align*}
for $n\ne 0,-1,-2,\ldots$. Here $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

**Addendum.** I derive an estimate for the absolute error when $n>0$. From the above, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k^n {\rm e}^{ - k} } } \right) - 1 & = 2\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{m - 1} \binom{n+m-1}{m-1}\frac{{\zeta (n + m)}}{{(2\pi )^{n + m} }}\cos \left( {\frac{{\pi (n + m)}}{2}} \right)} 
\\ & = \frac{{( - 1)^{n} }}{\pi }{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\binom{n+m}{m}\frac{{\zeta (n + m + 1)}}{{( - 2\pi {\rm i})^{n + m} }}} 
\\ &  = \frac{{( - 1)^{n} }}{\pi }{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\binom{n+m}{m}\frac{1}{{( - 2\pi {\rm i}k)^{n + m} }}} } 
\\ &  =  2\,{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2\pi {\rm i}k + 1)^{n + 1} }}} .
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
\left| {\frac{1}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k^n {\rm e}^{ - k} } } \right) - 1} \right| \le 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\left| {2\pi {\rm i}k + 1} \right|^{n + 1} }}}  = 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(4\pi ^2 k^2  + 1)^{(n + 1)/2} }}} .
$$

Comment: Very nice! For integer $n$ that second-to-last identity looks like what you'd get by computing the residues at every pole of the generating function.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!