# Sum of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^ne^{-k}$ for a positive integer $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, eulers-number-e, eulerian-numbers

How can we calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^ne^{-k}$ for a positive integer $n$? I tried: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^ne^{-k} =(-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d^n}{dy^n}\bigg|_{y=1}e^{-ky}=(-1)^n \frac{d^n}{dy^n}\bigg|_{y=1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-ky}  = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dy^n}\bigg|_{y=1} \frac{1}{1-e^{-y}}$$
but I got stuck for getting $\frac{d^n}{dy^n}\bigg|_{y=1} \frac{1}{1-e^{-y}}$ for general $n$. Is there a way for getting this, or is there another approach?

P.S. What I am actually wanting to compute is the value $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sum_k k^n e^{-k})/n!$.

From @Will Jagy's answer I've got the following: the function $f(x)=x^ne^{-x}$ is increasing for $x<n$ and decreasing for $x>n$, so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^ne^{-k}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^ne^{-k} + n^ne^{-n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^ne^{-k} \leq \int_0^n x^ne^{-x}dx+n^ne^{-n}+\int_n^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=n!+n^ne^{-n}$. But doesn't $n^ne^{-n}$ grow too fast as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: If you want to avoid some unnecessary negative signs, then it will help to use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-e^{-y}}=\frac{e^y}{e^y-1}$.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755773

Comment: Regarding your last question, by Stirling's formula $n^n \mathrm{e}^{-n} \sim \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ as $n\to+\infty$, which is enough for you to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} k^n e^{-k} = \sum_{l = 1}^n \left\langle \begin{matrix}n\\l\end{matrix}\right\rangle\frac{e^l}{(e-1)^{n+1}}, $$
where $$\left\langle \begin{matrix}n\\l\end{matrix}\right\rangle := \sum_{j = 0}^l (-1)^j {{n + 1} \choose j} (l + 1 - j)^n$$ are the [Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number), sometimes denoted $T(n, l)$, respectively. (We can also express the Eulerian numbers in terms of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).) See Richard R. Forberg's comment from 2015 February 15 in [OEIS A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292) (*Triangle of Eulerian numbers $T(n, k)$ ($n \geq 1$, $1 \leq k \leq n$) read by rows*), and see the rest of the entry for many beautiful combinatorial interpretations of the Eulerian Numbers. For small $n$ we have

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n & \sum_{k \geq 0} k^n e^{-k} \\
\hline
0 & \displaystyle \frac{1}{e - 1} & 0.58197\ldots\\
1 & \displaystyle \frac{e}{(e - 1)^2} & 0.92067\ldots \\
2 & \displaystyle \frac{e (e + 1)}{(e - 1)^3} & 1.99229\ldots \\
3 & \displaystyle \frac{e (e^2 + 4 e + 1)}{(e - 1)^4} & 6.00651\ldots \\
4 & \displaystyle \frac{e (e^3 + 11 e^2 + 11 e + 1)}{(e - 1)^4} & 24.00333\ldots \\
\end{array}$$

More generally (i.e., for arbitrary $n$) the definition of the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) gives
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} k^n e^{-k} = \operatorname{Li}_{-n}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) .$$

We can of course discard the $k = 0$ term in our sums, in which case taking $n = -1$ gives the special value
$$\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{e^{-k}}{k} = \operatorname{Li}_1\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) = 1 - \log(e - 1) ) = 0.45867 \ldots .$$

For large $n$ we should expect that the sum is asymptotic to $\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \,dx = n!$ (already the numerical approximations in our table for small $n$ suggest as much), and hence that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k \geq 0} k^n e^{-k}}{n!} = 1 .$$ Indeed, the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755028/approximation-of-gamma-function-via-riemann-sums-at-integer-points/4755773) (h/t Gary) yield the explicit asymptotic
$$\frac{\sum_{k \geq 0} k^n e^{-k}}{n!} - 1 \in O((2 \pi)^{-n}) .$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755773 regarding your last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, @Gary! I've added a reference to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^ne^{-k}$  is approximated well enough by
$$  I_n =   \int_0^\infty  x^n e^{-x}  dx  $$
At the same time, $$ I_n = n!$$
I did that by induction and integration by parts.

So the limit you care about is $1$

=========================================================

Let's see, $x^n e^{-x}$  is increasing until its maximum at $x = n,$  then decreases  down to zero at infinity.

For the estimates,  for monotonic functions we have:

if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{k=a}^b \;  f(k) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a comment for my new edit?